# Wordpress Custom select query transformation to Wp_Query with args

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone please help me to transform the below query in Wp_query structure with args.

```
select post.ID, post.post_title, post.post_status, post.post_date, post.post_modified,post.post_author,ads.pack_name
    from wp_posts as post
        join wp_ads as ads on post.ID = ads.post_id
            where post.post_type = 'ad_listing'
            and post.post_status = 'publish'
            order by pack_id Desc
```

Where Wp_ads is extra table created by me and not a default WordPress table.I want to convert it into this format so that looping and structuring can be easy.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query($args
```

I the query in format so that i can use have_post for looping.Below is the code with select query which is not working for pagination.

```
   <?php
global $cp_options;
global $wpdb;
?>
<!-- Custom query for ads ordering {Featured,Urgent,Free} -->
<?php 

$querystr_AllPosts = "
    select post.ID, post.post_title, post.post_status, post.post_date, post.post_modified,post.post_author,ads.pack_name
        from wp_posts as post
            join wp_ads as ads on post.ID = ads.post_id
                where post.post_type = 'ad_listing'
                and post.post_status = 'publish'
                order by pack_id Desc
    ";
    $result_AllPosts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr_AllPosts,OBJECT);

    /*Pagination Code*/
    $ppp = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
    $wp_query->found_posts = count($result_AllPosts);
    $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $ppp);
    $on_page = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
        if($on_page == 0)
        { 
            $on_page = 1;
         }      
    $offset = ($on_page-1) * $ppp;
    /*End Of Pagination Code*/

    $querystr_SelectedPosts = "
    select post.ID, post.post_title, post.post_status, post.post_date, post.post_modified,post.post_author,ads.pack_name
        from wp_posts as post
            join wp_ads as ads on post.ID = ads.post_id
                where post.post_type = 'ad_listing'
                and post.post_status = 'publish'
                order by pack_id Desc LIMIT $ppp OFFSET $offset
    ";
    $result_SelectedPosts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr_SelectedPosts,OBJECT);
    foreach($result_SelectedPosts as $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
?>

<?php appthemes_before_loop(); ?>


        <?php appthemes_before_post(); ?>

        <div class="post-block-out <?php cp_display_style( 'featured' ); ?>">

            <div class="post-block">

                <div class="post-left">

                    <?php if ( $cp_options->ad_images ) cp_ad_loop_thumbnail(); ?>

                </div>

                <div class="<?php cp_display_style( array( 'ad_images', 'ad_class' ) ); ?>">

                    <?php appthemes_before_post_title(); ?>

                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( mb_strlen( get_the_title() ) >= 75 ) echo mb_substr( get_the_title(), 0, 75 ).'...'; else the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <?php appthemes_after_post_title(); ?>

                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <?php appthemes_before_post_content(); ?>

                    <p class="post-desc"><?php echo cp_get_content_preview( 160 ); ?></p>

                    <?php appthemes_after_post_content(); ?>

                    <div class="clr"></div>

                </div>

                <div class="clr"></div>

            </div><!-- /post-block -->

        </div><!-- /post-block-out -->

        <?php appthemes_after_post(); ?>



    <?php appthemes_after_endwhile(); ?>


<?php appthemes_after_loop(); ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php wp_pagenavi();?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: what is the problem in this query?

Comment: The query is working fine but with select query i am having problems in pagination.I cannot use the result of select query for have_post().It gives error saying Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object....

Comment: you don't need to use `have_post()`, slightly modification in you query may give the desired result. please share your query

Comment: $ppp = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
 $wp_query->found_posts = count($result_AllPosts);
 $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $ppp);
 $on_page = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
  if($on_page == 0)
  { 
   $on_page = 1;
   }  
 $offset = ($on_page-1) * $ppp;

Comment: $querystr_SelectedPosts = "
 select post.ID, post.post_title, post.post_status, post.post_date, post.post_modified,post.post_author,ads.pack_name
  from wp_posts as post
   join wp_ads as ads on post.ID = ads.post_id
    where post.post_type = 'ad_listing'
    and post.post_status = 'publish'
    order by pack_id Desc LIMIT $ppp OFFSET $offset
 ";
 $result_SelectedPosts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr_SelectedPosts,OBJECT);
 foreach($result_SelectedPosts as $post):
   setup_postdata($post);

Comment: The first post has pagination logic and in second post i have inserted Limit and offset in select query for pagination.

Comment: you should use edit link under the question, and update it with your codes. Its hard to understand for anyone.

Comment: ok sorry i am new to this interface